# Image Count Indicator in Android

Tags: android, image

I am displaying an image gallery consisting of 15 images with image displayed on the screen (full-screen) at a time. When the user swipes across, the image changes. I am looking at a small polka-dots style indicator at the center-bottom of the screen to show the image count and where the user currently is.

eg: If my gallery held 5 images and the user was currently on the 3rd image, then there would be 5 polka dots with 3rd dot highlighted/filled with color and the rest polka-dots be hollow.

I know the description might sound a little vague but in short, I am looking at an image count indicator! :)

Thanks!

Comment: how do you display the images? what view? can u give us the layout xml?

Comment: I use the Gallery tutorial from here: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gallery.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know exactly what you want, you are looking for the PageControl that is used on iPhones with the Scroll Views. I have never seen anything like that for Android. You would have to build a custom view. It's explained here:

[Building Custom Android Components](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html)

Comment: Thanks for the info Nick.  I am pretty sure they have it for android and you can see it when you swipe across home screens.

Comment: Let me know when you find it.

Answer (score 1):

You might check out this Android Count Indicator project: https://github.com/rupertbates/android-count-indicator

Answer (score 0):

I finally found it in the [Launcher code!](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Launcher2.git;a=tree)